# How to build linux tools via MingW64 in 2021?

Tags: mingw-w64

I'm trying to follow this example to build wget2:
https://gnutoolchains.com/building/

I've installed `x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0` preset (?) and first tried to build old version of wget1, but I've reached dead end. There is no way to run `./configure` to create build target rules. Did I install something wrong? How I'm supposed to know what exactly is to install? Is it each new preset for each application I want to build? How I'm supposed to handle the insane list of requirements of wget2:

https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2#build-requirements

And lastly - why is it so jank? Is it by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to run `./configure` on Windows. You need [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) for that, which will give you a bash shell and the tools needed by `./configure`.

[MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) comes with a package manager (`pacman`) which allows you to install a more recent MinGW-w64.